# android app.gradle secret Key from Server

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-places-api, android-security, secret-key

In my **app.gradle** (where all the dependencies are) I have to include **multiple Secret Keys** such as the Google Place API Key, OneSignal API Key etc etc.

I know that all Secret Keys must be stored on the Server and that's what I do in my App.
However, I don't know how to put those Keys from Firebase Database to this **app.gradle** file.

I have been seaching around but couldn't find anything.
Could someone help please?

Cheers

Comment: What specific secret keys from Firebase are you talking about? Because the Firebase Database URL and API key are just configuration data and can (and should) be in the app code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Hi Puff! Thanks for having a look at my issue.Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself properly, but what I mean is that my Secret Keys are stored in my Firebase Database (except for the Firebase URL, which is in the gradle.properties) and I need to put some of them in the app.gradle file.